# How to get screen width in dpi?

Tags: android, width, screen

How can I get the screen width dpi?

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
int f = metrics.densityDpi;


  //  getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);

int width = metrics.widthPixels;
int dp = (int)(width / (metrics.density));
```

I do this, so lets assume my densitydpi is 120..and widthpixel 240..
via calculation i get 240/0.75.... so I have 320 widthdpi?

However that's not the case....widthdpi is smaller then 320 I think...because 320 goes with me wrong in the screen.... using 120 works.

on Nexus 4...with width 768 and densitydpi 320...I divide 768/2 and i get 384 correct width density dpi (it works)

But on other ones like 240, 160, 120 density dpi..the calculation of width dpi seems wrong ...

Comment: there is something i add. for example in the above case... if i do layout_margin 20 dp...and i deduct 40 from 320...i should get 280..but i get sthg like 240 ... so widthdpi is calculated wrong

Comment: For most apps, there's no reason to calculate these values, assuming you are writing a layout and using dp values all along (which will automatically scale things correctly no matter what density display the device has).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Per the [Supporting Multiple Screens guide's definition of DP](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#terms)

```
px = dp * (dpi / 160)
```

Therefore

```
dp = px / (dpi / 160)
```

or equivalently

```
dp = px * 160 / dpi
```

Remember that dp stands for 'density-independent pixel' - i.e., 1dp is the same physical size on a ldpi device as it is on an xxhdpi device. Therefore you should expect all phones to have roughly ~300-400dp of width, noting the bucket sizes by dp:

- xlarge screens are at least 960dp x 720dp
- large screens are at least 640dp x 480dp
- normal screens are at least 470dp x 320dp
- small screens are at least 426dp x 320dp

Comment: dp = (int) (width * 160 / metrics.densityDpi); i do that, i think i still get it wrong

Comment: on screen of 240-320 px with density dpi 120. i get by calculation my screen width dp 320... however if i write 120dp width it takes all width as well.

Comment: You'll have to include more code on where you are using these values as you haven't explained what takes all width or what you are trying to do with these values, but the documentation on how to calculate dp is not incorrect.

Comment: i am using this https://github.com/floydfix/Android-Easy-Captcha in mathcaptchaactivity i give Captcha c = new MathCaptcha(dp, 100, MathOptions.PLUS_MINUS_MULTIPLY);   here the dp whether i give it 320 or 120 for the device with 240-320 px and densitydpi 120 i get all width taken

Comment: hey, i fixed it up. the problem was here im.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(c.width*2 , c.height *2)); it was working for 320 dpi.... all what i did is i multpily by metrics.density instead of 2. thisis why on device 120 dpi..it was mutiplying 320*2 = 640... now its 320*0.75 = 240 ....

Comment: Great! Always a good feeling when you are able to find the root problem. If this answer helped, please do accept the answer.